# How to use pyautogui for images

Tags: python, pyautogui

I was wondering if it was possible to do `pyautogui.locateOnScreen()` for a full folder this is what i mean a folder with 20 different images and finding them on the screen. Is it possible to do with `pyautogui`? or else how would you do it?

This is my code so far:

```
from pyautogui import locateAllOnScreen as find
import os
import numpy as np




def try_to_find(x):
    x = os.path.isfile(x)
    if x == None:
        Warning('No images were enterd')   
        
    else:
        folder = x
        value = find(folder)
        
        if value is not None:
            print(f"{x} was found!")
            
        else:
            if value is None:
                print(f"{x} was not found!")
                
        return(list(value))



myfolder = ("ImageQuery")
found = 0

with os.scandir(myfolder) as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        if entry.is_file():
            found+=1
            print(f'Items {found}: {entry.name}')
            try_to_find(entry.name)
```

i get this error if i run this code `TypeError: expected an image filename, OpenCV numpy array, or PIL image`

Comment: yes, pyautogui would be able to do this if all of the images are currently displayed on your screen. This link is generally helpful. https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter20/

Comment: @Hooded0ne could you please provide a bit more detail? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
import os
import pyautogui as py


image_list = []

# Get list of all files in current directory
directory = os.listdir()

# Find files that end with .png or .jpg and add to image_list
for file in directory:
    if file.endswith('.png') or file.endswith('.jpg'):
        image_list.append(file)

# Loop through list to find all the images
for image in image_list:
    print(image)
    print(py.locateOnScreen(image))
```

This question is similar to another [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044841/pyautogui-locateonscreen-for-multiple-images), I posted the same answer in both places.